# Connect from my website to a MySQL database hosted in another computer using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I got this problem, let's see if some one here can give me a hand with it.

I got a website hosted in a computer, with its own database, and I can access it from any computer using the domain pointing to it or its public address.

Using PHP I'm running a little script (on my website) that connects to another database and brings some information; the thing is that this other database is hosted in a computer within a VPN (using Hamachi) where the client doesn't have access but the server does.

If I connect from the server using

Mysql -h (IP_ADDRESS_ON_THE_VPN) -u user -p

It connects perfectly, so no firewall problem / connection problem.

But if I open the PHP script from a client, it says:

*"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. "*

in other words: timeout...

Another test I made is connect the client to the VPN, **and that way works perfectly!**, strage... doesn't PHP run on the server? What't the best approach here?

Thanks for you time.

EDIT:
@Martin Cup
Here's some of the code I use to make the connection, I´m almost sure that there´s not a problem in the code since it works if I add the client to the network.

```
 try{
           $DB_CTE = new PDO('mysql:host='.$SRV.';port='.$PUERTO.';dbname='.$BASE,$USU,$PASS, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
       } catch (PDOException $e) {
           echo 'Error: '  . $e->getMessage() . '<br><br>HOST:'.$SRV.'<br><br>Data CNX:' . $SRV ."(".$BASE.")".$PUERTO;
           exit;
       }
       $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' .$BASE. '.xxx ORDER BY FEC_EMI LIMIT 10 ';
       try{
           $query = $DB_CTE->prepare($sql);;
           $query->execute();
           $list = $query->fetchAll();
           $xxx = array();
           foreach ($list as $rs) {
                echo "VTA: ".$rs['ID_FCV']."T_T: ".$rs['T_T']."\n\r";
           }
       } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Error: '  . $e->getMessage() . '<br><br>SQL:' . $sql;
            exit;
       }
```

@Hackerman
I have root access to the database, and all host are avalible 'root'@'%', I'm sure of it since connect to it from serval computers. What I want to do now is to publish some info from that computer in the web (connecting to that database), I also can't stablish one IP address per client since it will be public and I don't know how many and from where clients will be connecting. 
Hope this makes sense.

Comment: So connecting from the server it's not the issue...look, you need to create an user for the client machine...first you need to get the ip of your client machine and create an user on your server for that ip

Comment: can you post some of the PHP code that is establishing the connection that returns the error?

Comment: Tip: you don't need to @-reply in your post edits. After you've made an edit based on feedback, just leave a comment to let the person know you've made an update.